# SQL Query Table for Changes to record based on previous record (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for my impending question, but I'm probably a bit over my head here... SQL was not something I was trained in, and it's been a learn-as-you-go endeavor. I am trying to query an existing single table in SQL Server 2008 (*in Compatibility mode for SQL Server **2000***).

The table structure as similar to the following:

```
Table1
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|   Date   | RecordID | Revision | AttribA | AttribB | AttribC |  AttribD   | AttribE |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        0 | mammal  | horse   | slimy   | tasty      | Grade 4 |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        1 | mammal  | dog     | slimy   | tasty      | Grade 3 |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        2 | mammal  | dog     | soft    | tasty      | Grade 2 |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        3 | mammal  | dog     | soft    | lick       | Grade 2 |
| 1/1/2014 |        2 |        0 | puppet  | sock    | soft    | less tasty | Grade 9 |
| 1/1/2014 |        2 |        1 | puppet  | sock    | soft    | not tasty  | Grade 9 |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
```

`RecordID` and `RevisionNum` are `Primary Keys`. There may be multiple revisions of a single `RecordID` stored in the `Table1` as a form of Audit History.

In addition, let's say AttributeA & AttributeB are unofficially related as Group A,
AttributeC & AttributeD are related as Group B, and AttributeE is on its own as Group C.

My task is to write a query that, given a `RecordID`, will return the following:

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|   Date   | RecordID | Revision | Group A | Group B | Group C |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        0 |         |         |         |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        1 |    X    |         |     X   |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        2 |         |    X    |     X   |
| 1/1/2014 |        1 |        3 |         |    X    |         |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Where the query returns an entry for each revision for a single record with 'X' if any column in the "Group" was updated from the previous value.

So far my best attempt has been to set:

```
DECLARE  @ID   INTEGER
DECLARE  @Revision  INTEGER
SET @ID = 1
SET @Revision = 3
...
  SET @GroupA = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT AttribA, AttribB
    FROM [dbo].[Table1]
    WHERE RecordID = @ID 
      AND RevisionID in (@Revision ,@Revision -1)) A)
... 
SELECT @ID
      ,[RevisionID]
      ,[Date]
      ,[GroupA] =
        CASE 
          WHEN @GroupA = 1 THEN ''
          ELSE 'X'
        END
...
  FROM [dbo].[Table1]
  WHERE RecordID = @ID
    AND RevisionID = @Revision
```

I've cut out some duplicate code to show you the general strategy, but I honestly think it's a complete mess that I doubt I'll be able to remedy without turning it into a nightmare. Could anyone give me a tip on how they might better complete the task described in SQL Server 2000 compatibility? I appreciate any assistance here.

Comment: I think I understand the question, but the given example result  doesn't seem to match the example data. Am I misunderstanding? Can you revise the question, to ensure I don't misunderstand.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. The data in the sample query isn't consistent with the sample data in the table. I'll fix it now!

Comment: And unfortunately no, the database is preexisting, old, and must retain SQL Server 2000 compatibility.

Comment: why group C only have one 'x' ?

Answer (score 1):

try below sql:

**UPDATED**
change the inner join to left join. ;)

```
select a.RecordId,a.Revision
    , Case When a.AttribA +' '+a.AttribB <> ab.[Group A] then 'X' else '' End as 'Group A'
    , Case When a.AttribC +' '+a.AttribD <> ab.[Group B] then 'X' else '' End as 'Group B'
    , Case When a.AttribE <> ab.[Group C] then 'X' else '' End as 'Group C'
    , a.AttribA +' '+a.AttribB as 'Group A'
    , a.AttribC+ ' ' + a.AttribD as 'Group B'
    , a.AttribE as 'Group C'
    , ab.[Group A] as 'PrevRevision A'
    , ab.[Group B] as 'PrevRevision B'
    , ab.[Group C] as 'PrevRevision C'
from @tempData a
left join
(
    select b.RecordId,b.Revision
    , b.AttribA +' '+b.AttribB as 'Group A'
    , b.AttribC+ ' ' + b.AttribD as 'Group B'
    , b.AttribE as 'Group C'
    from @tempData b

) ab on a.RecordId=ab.RecordId and a.Revision = ab.Revision + 1

order by a.RecordId, a.Revision
```

Result Data:

```
RecordId    Revision    Group A Group B Group C Group A       Group B         Group C  PrevRevision A   PrevRevision B   PrevRevision C
----------- ----------- ------- ------- ------- ------------- --------------- -------- ---------------- ---------------- --------------- 
1           0                                   mammal horse  slimy tasty     Grade 4  NULL             NULL             NULL
1           1           X               X       mammal dog    slimy tasty     Grade 3  mammal horse     slimy tasty      Grade 4
1           2                   X       X       mammal dog    soft tasty      Grade 2  mammal dog       slimy tasty      Grade 3
1           3                   X               mammal dog    soft lick       Grade 2  mammal dog       soft tasty       Grade 2
2           0                                   puppet sock   soft less tasty Grade 9  NULL             NULL             NULL
2           1                   X               puppet sock   soft not tasty  Grade 9  puppet sock      soft less tasty  Grade 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the limitations of SQL Server 2000, but perhaps this approach would work:

```
select 
  RecordID,
  Revision, 
  AttribA,
  AttribB,
  ( select 'X' 
    from t1 as B
    where B.RecordID = A.RecordID
    and   B.Revision = A.revision - 1
    and  (B.AttribA <> A.AttribA or B.AttribB <> A.AttribB)
  ) AS GroupA
from t1 as A
where RecordID = 1
;
```

Here is a fiddle which shows it running: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4626e/6